# Laravel and MongoDB configuration not working

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.5, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm trying to configure Laravel 5 with MongoDB by this [link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#installation).

**Error**

> D:\wamp\www\lfirst>composer require jenssegers/mongodb
>       You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
>       Using version ^3.0 for jenssegers/mongodb
>       ./composer.json has been updated
>
> > php artisan clear-compiled
> >         Loading composer repositories with package information
> >         Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> >         Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> ```
> Problem 1
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb (locked at 1.0.2) -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.2].
>
>    To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
> - D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
>    You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
>   Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
>
>  D:\wamp\www\lfirst>php --ini
>  Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
>  Loaded Configuration File:         D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
>  Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
>  Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
> ```

**Note**

I using Window server; for other projects I'm using MongoDB too but it's process is only a problem with Laravel.

Comment: you have to install mongodb extension for php

Comment: Yes, sure, I run `composer show -p`, it's show that `ext-mongo           1.6.8    The mongo PHP extension
`, I think that I correct at all

Comment: ext-mongodb and ext-mongo are two different things.
mongodb is recommended, mongo is a deprecated one.

Comment: could you point me a bout it?

Comment: [This is the one that he's talking about](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). You should be moving to that extension due to the deprecation in the `mongo` estension.

Comment: In this [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.1.3/windows) I can find the mongodb driver (php_mongodb.dll) for PHP on Windows systems. Download the correct version for PHP and the system (x86 or x64) driver. Copy this DLL in the extension folder, in my case C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext and add this line in php.ini: extension=php_mongodb.dll. Restart the Apache server and try again. Note that you must edit the php.ini file in this path (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16, if used Wamp) and not Wamp icon on the taskbar.

Comment: I hope can help to someone meet problem like me